# Created a Desktop Application with PyInstaller but It doesn't work on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I developed a Desktop Application in Python on my Mac using PyCharm. 
Then I used pyinstaller to pack it and try to use it on Windows 10 and Windows 7 but when I try to run on windows 10 i have the error :
This app can’t run on your PC check with software publisher.

I tried to set every possible setting on windows 10, from SmartScreen to security policy to allow external developer. Nothing. So I thought could be something about pyinstaller.

Ideas?

Comment: Is win10 64-bit?

Comment: yes it is. But I should use this also on a 32-bit in future

Comment: Although I don't know your problem,you should use `pyinstaller` on 32-bit if you want to use this exe in 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: hope to receive a good tip on this problem..

Comment: You need to build on windows to use on windows. If you build on mac, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller is not cross platform.

[See the documentation here.](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html), specifically the Note near the top of the page.

If you want to run on Windows, you must compile on Windows. Same for Mac OS and Linux.

Solutions to your particular problem:

- Simply use a different machine to compile, with the relevant OS, if available.
- A virtual machine on your Mac ([VirtualBox for example](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) with Windows installed inside it.

As far as I know, there is no other way around this. No tricks or clever hacks... Sorry!